# Java EE RESTful Web Services Security w/ HMAC how to intercept requests?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, interceptor

I'm developing an application which deploys some RESTful web services, I want to use a HMACSHA512 signature method but would rather not have to implement it in every published web service.

So I'm looking for a way to intercept the request before it reaches the REST WS, and have a custom class, that based on the HttpHeaders/UriInfo/etc and on the HMAC digest, etc, would decide if it is valid or not and forward to the REST WS or deny it.

I'm seen some stuff about ResourceFactoryFilter, adding a filter to the web.xml, etc, but I'm lost..

Anyone with knowledge about this can give me some tips on how I would implement this? Specially, the best way to achieve this and how the parts would interact.

How I imagined what I want to do: Client <-> Interceptor -> REST WS -> …

Thank you for your time.

P.S.: I would like to achieve this without 3rd party frameworks like Spring.

Comment: Do you mean a `ServletFilter` (javax.servlet.Filter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a ServletFilter class that you configure in your web.xml for the particular URL prefixes you want checked.

That class will have a `doFilter` method, and in that method you do the validation.  If successful, you continue the processing by calling `chain.doFilter()`; otherwise throw an exception.

Comment: Depending on which version of JAX-RS you're using (some of the terms you used are JAX-RS terms) there might be an equivalent to a servlet filter that gives you more access to JAX-RS internals.

Comment: So easy. It's hard to believe all my web search wouldn't show that. Thank you very much!